# how can I use StrSubstitutor with and empty variable suffix?

Tags: java, string, apache-commons-lang, apache-commons-lang3

I am trying to use Apache Commons Lang's [`StrSubstitutor`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) to replace variables in a string marked only using prefixes, e.g. like named parameters markjed with `:` in an SQL query.

Here's the code snippet I am using, which doesn't work.

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrMatcher;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor;

Map<String,String> m = ImmutableMap.of("a", 1);

StrSubstitutor strSubstitutor = new StrSubstitutor(m)
        .setVariablePrefix(":")
        .setVariableSuffix("");
System.out.println(strSubstitutor.replace("select a from t where a = :a"));
// expect select a from t where a = 1
```

Any idea how to do it?

I am trying to implement a custom `StrMatcher` but am still unsuccessful.
Any one has done it before and can share some experience?

Answer (score 3):

After a deep delving into the code of `StrSubstitutor` I realized it cannot be done using the `StrSubstitutor`/`StrMatcher` API.
Since Spring's `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` does not expose the sql with replaced parameter values, I had to implement my own sql parameter substitutor.